# System of Differential equations on non uniform grid

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I need to solve the following set of ODE's numerically,

$\frac{dy}{dx}=Ay+Bz, \\
\frac{dz}{dx}=Cy+Dz$

where the independent variable $x$ is an ***non-uniform spaced*** array of points and so is A, B, C & D.

What is the best way of achieving this as common NDsolve specifies the independent variable in $ \{x,x_{min},x_{max}\} $ format.

Comment: You could use `Interpolation` to get functions for A,B,C,D, and then use `NDSolve`or `DSolve`

Comment: @DanielHuber Thanks! but what about the fact that  $x$ is non-uniformly spaced?

Comment: Interpolate will do linear interpolation. After solving the DE, you will end up with a functions for y[x] and  z[x], that you can evaluate at your non-uniformly spaced points.

Comment: Although `NDSolve` returns a continuous `InterpolatingFunction`, behind the scenes, it does discretize your equation -- most likely nonuniformly.  Check out the `NDSolve` docs for more info.